# Hbase scan commands into a text file in windows

Tags: azure, hadoop, hbase, azure-hdinsight

Is it possible to capture the 
hbase command "scan table" to a textfile.

The command goes like this :

```
hbase(main):001:0>scan sampletable
```

I tried using the command prompt command

```
hbase(main):001:0>scan sampletable > textfile.txt
```

but gives error as "wrong number of arguments"

I tried with the following commands as well :

```
hbase(main):001:0>echo "scan 'sampletable'" | hbase shell | grep "^ " > registration.txt
```

but there is exception "unrecognised characters ^ " in the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute linux commands like echo, hbase etc in hbase shell. You need to execute these commands in windows power shell.

Exit from hbase shell and execute the below command

`echo "scan 'sampletable'" | hbase shell | grep "^ " > registration.txt`

Comment: But will it recognize the hbase commands from the powershell cmd window?

Comment: Because Powershell is piping the commands into the hbase shell.  Hbase shell is still doing the interpretation.  @h4ck3r is right.  I do this in Bash all the time.

Comment: If you have properly set hbase bin directory in System PATH, hbase command will be available in powershell.